# PSD slicing outsourcing service

Tags: css, xhtml, slice

There are a couple of online services that offer PSD to XHTML/CSS. Which one do you recommend? How should I choose one?

Answer (score 6):

First, I recommend using someone in your own network of people first. If you know someone with this skill who is open to freelancing, offer the project to them. Talk to local schools with web design/development classes and ask if they keep a list of freelance students.  Build up your business relationships with people close to you.

If that doesn't work, choose one online the way you would choose anything. Research. Look at their portfolios. Go to one of the sites they did and "view source" in your browser to look at their code. Ask a web developer friend if she thinks it's well done. Look at more than one example and make sure they have consistent quality. Try to find out how long they've been around. (Do a whois search and find out how long the site has been registered, for one). Look at the person's resume if they offer it, or ask for a resume and any references they may have. You might even try to contact one of their clients and ask how their experience was with them.

In the end, when you've balanced price and your research, you have to take a leap of faith, but with your research, you probably will choose well.

Comment: +1 really a nice answer. specially "Build up your business relationships with people close to you."

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider learning how to do it yourself.  I find that even with a complex design, I usually spend 90% of my time making the design in Photoshop and only 10% converting that to HTML+CSS.  It's really worth getting to know HTML and CSS inside-out so you can complete the process.

Answer (score 1):

Some clue here

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/375934/11063214233-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/375934/11063214233-My-Desktop.png)

You can get help from this site

http://www.psdtohtmlreviews.com/

And I think this one is mostly recommended

http://designshack.co.uk/articles/reviews/psd-to-html-by-psd2html

**But first of all consider answer of @josh**

And here are links of some good tutorials of PSD 2 HTML conversion http://www.bestpsdtohtml.com/20-best-psd-to-xhtml-css-tutorials/

You can learn yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you have to convert for once you may look at http://csswithcolour.com/

and if you have requirements for many projects or future projects then
http://htmlbutcher.com/ looks to be a good tool.

Comment: Have you worked with csswithcolour.com? How's the quality of their code?

Comment: I haven't used it but have got good feedback from others about it. You can check their testimonials as well.

http://www.csswithcolour.com/testimonials